# Как обновить ACCESS-TOKEN в Retrofit2/RxJava2

Tags: java, android, rxjava, retrofit2

Я делаю запрос (любой, авторизация, регистрация и тд) и только потом узнаю, что нужно обновить `TOKEN`, то есть получаю ошибку `401`.

Вот запрос для авторизации:

```
BaseApplication.getApiClient()
                .signIn(accessToken, body)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<UserProfile>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        Log.d("-- SignInOnSubscribe", "Subscribed!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UserProfile userProfile) {
                        if (userProfile.getErrorDetails() != null) {
                            onSignInFinishedCallback.onLoginFailure(userProfile.getErrorDetails());
                            Log.d("-- SignInOnError", userProfile.getErrorDetails());
                        } else {
                            onSignInFinishedCallback.onLoginSuccess(userProfile);
                            profileRepository.updateUserProfile(userProfile);

                            Log.d("-- SignInOnSuccess", userProfile.getName());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d("-- SignInOnError", e.getMessage());

                        if (e.getMessage().equals(Constants.CODE_UNAUTHORIZED)){
                            // Действие при ошибке 401
                        }

                        onSignInFinishedCallback.onLoginFailure(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Сами запросы к API:

```
@POST("/api/login")
Single<UserProfile> getAccessToken(@Body Map<String, String> requestBody);

@POST("/api/abonent/login")
Single<UserProfile> signIn(@Header("X-ACCESS-TOKEN") String accessToken,
                             @Body Map<String, String> requestBody);
```

Скажем, запрос на авторизацию - `запрос 1`, запрос на получение `TOKEN` - `запрос 2`.

Вопрос: Как обновить `TOKEN` если получил ошибку в `запросе 1` и после успеха `запроса 2`, обратно делать `запрос 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Задачу рефреша токена можно решить с помощью OkHttp Interceptors.

Что такое `Interceptor`?  Это класс, который перехватывает все ваши запросы выполняемые через заданный `OkHttClient`.

Его надо подключить к клиенту, пример :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new TokenRefresherInterceptor())
    .build();
```

Что делать в интерсепторе?

```
class TokenRefresherInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request(); // получили запрос который вы отправили на сервер.
    Response response = chain.proceed(request); //тут выполняется запрос и результат в response.

    //далее вы работаете с этим response. 
//Проверяете, какой ответ вам пришел.
 //Если в нём лежит 401. значит вы формируете запрос на обновление токена, //выполняете его в этом же интерсепторе дальше. и снова проверяете результат. 

//если токен рефрешнулся то повторяете изначальный запрос

    return response;
  }
}
```

Подробнее есть множество статей на эту тему в гугле)